# Implement String() on a map with interface{} values

Tags: dictionary, go

How could I write a function to print a map object in Go (Golang)? Right now I have this, but it doesn't compile. It returns `cannot convert value (type interface {}) to type reflect.Kind: need type assertion`.

```
package main

type MyDictionary map[string]interface{}

func (d MyDictionary) String() string {
    var stringBuffer bytes.Buffer

    for key, value := range d {
        stringBuffer.WriteString(key)
        stringBuffer.WriteString(": ")

        valueType := reflect.Kind(value)

        switch valueType {
        case reflect.String:
            log.Println("string") // just to check if this block gets executed
            // Add to stringBuffer

        case reflect.Float64:
            log.Println("float64") // just to check if this block gets executed
            // Add to stringBuffer

        default:
            log.Println("Error: type was", valueType)
        }
    }

    return stringBuffer.String()
}

func main() {
    var dict MyDictionary = make(MyDictionary)
    dict["hello"] = "world"
    dict["floating"] = 10.0
    dict["whole"] = 12

    fmt.Println(dict)
}
```

I want `String()` to return a string like `hello: world\nfloating: 10.0\nwhole: 12\n`. That I can then pass to `fmt.Println()` to print this. In Java, I would use `StringBuilder` for this.

```
hello: world
floating: 10.0
whole: 12
```

I also tried switching on `value.(type)` with `case string:` and `case float64`, but then I didn't know how to write those values to `stringBuffer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an idiomatic solution.

```
func (d MyDictionary) String() string {
    var buf bytes.Buffer

    for k, v := range d {
        buf.WriteString(k + ": ")

        // v is an interface{} here
        switch v := v.(type) {
        // The inner v is typed. It shadows the outer interface{} v. That's
        // the idiomatic part.
        case string:
            buf.WriteString(v + "\n") // v is a string
        case int:
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintln(v)) // v is an int
        case float64:
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintln(v)) // v is a float64
        }
    }

    return buf.String()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can potentially simplify it to this ([<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/DTNGzCP7tk)):

```
func (d MyDictionary) String() string {
    var result string

    for key, value := range d {
        result += fmt.Sprintf("%s: %v\n", key, value)
    }

    return result
}
```

Which prints:

```
hello: world
floating: 10
whole: 12
```

Obviously, the "whole" floating point has the decimals removed (if you set it to `10.5` it will print properly). If that's required, then you'll want to switch on the `float` and specify precision as well ([<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/iSplz6DggZ)):

```
func (d MyDictionary) String() string {
    var result string

    for key, value := range d {
        switch value.(type) {
        case float64:
            result += fmt.Sprintf("%s: %.2f\n", key, value)
        default:
            result += fmt.Sprintf("%s: %v\n", key, value)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Which prints:

```
floating: 10.00
whole: 12
hello: world
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to get the type of the interface and then switch on the kind of the type.

```
valueType := reflect.TypeOf(value).Kind()
```

Working Example: http://play.golang.org/p/a-7SePUzZ-

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "reflect"
)

type MyDictionary map[string]interface{}

func (d MyDictionary) String() string {
    var stringBuffer bytes.Buffer

    for key, value := range d {
        stringBuffer.WriteString(key)
        stringBuffer.WriteString(": ")

        valueType := reflect.TypeOf(value).Kind()

        switch valueType {
        case reflect.String:
            log.Println("string")
        default:
            log.Println("Type was:", valueType)
        }
    }

    return stringBuffer.String()
}

func main() {
    var dict MyDictionary = make(MyDictionary)
    dict["hello"] = "world"
    dict["floating"] = 10.0
    dict["whole"] = 12

    fmt.Println(dict)
}
```

Output

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 string
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Type was: float64
2009/11/10 23:00:00 Type was: int
hello: floating: whole:
```

Comment: Perhaps I was too vague. I want `String()` to return a string that concatenates all of the key and values to a single string and then returns that strings.